# What is the difference between forever loop inside fork block and fork block inside forever loop in systemverilog?

Tags: system-verilog

I have designed the test environment for the FIFO memory model in SystemVerilog, in which I am facing this issue .so which option is better for me?

When I used forever loop inside the fork block, then it is giving somewhat controlled output, but when I used fork inside forever, it is going to an infinite loop in the simulator.

ONE:

```
forever begin
  fork
    p1; //thread-1
    p2; //thread-2
  join
end
```

TWO:

```
fork
  forever begin
    p1;   //thread-1
    p2;   //thread-2
  end
join
```

According to my understanding, It doesn't make any difference. then why such different output is coming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are completely different, because execution after a `fork`-`join` block doesn't continue until after all the threads inside it have finished. So, your first example will launch the next pair of threads (P1 and P2) once the first pair have completed, eg (supposing P2 takes longer than P1):

```
|----P1----    |----P1----    |----P1----    |----P1----    |
|------P2------|------P2------|------P2------|------P2------|
```

But, in the second example, there is only one thread inside the `fork`-`join` block (the `forever` loop), so threads P1 and P2 execute sequentially:

```
|----P1----|------P2------|----P1----|------P2------|----P1----|------P2------|
```

Comment: But in first case , simulation is not ending and in second case simulation will end . If the both have same terminating condition then ,why just second case , reaches to the end.?

Comment: @ShraddhaDevaiya Without an [MCVE], I couldn't possibly say.

Comment: Ok I am creating minimal example, will upload as soon as possible. Thanks for your previous answer. I got your point.